# Mysql Order By for string

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

I am using below addressing method for my warehouse bins.

```
1-3-5
2-4-1
12-1-2
```

Now I want to sort them using Order by but the problem is 12-1-2 is coming before 2-4-1

While I need to be sorted like below

```
1-3-5
2-4-1
12-1-2
19-3-5
23-3-2
```

In fact each address in containing 3 different information:

```
Shelve-floor-bin
```

So I need to sort by Shelve first, then floor then bin.

Comment: Why is that a problem?

Comment: It looks like you want your values `p-q-r` ordered as if `p`, `q`, and `r` are each numeric values, not lexical values. In other words, you want `1-2-3` to come before `1-10-3`. Is that correct? Please consider an [edit] to your question to clarify your requirement.

Comment: Your comment is totally correct, edited my question also

Answer (score 0):

May Be this will work.

```
SELECT * FROM `tablename` ORDER By convert(`fieldtosory`, decimal) ASC
```

Comment: This solution is working only for first part, I mean it's sorting 1-x-x , 2-x-x , 12-x-x , 22-x-x properly but it's not working on second part , I mean 1-5-x is coming before 1-3-x

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT '2-1' x UNION SELECT '12-1' ORDER BY x;
+------+
| x    |
+------+
| 12-1 |
| 2-1  |
+------+

SELECT '2-1' x UNION SELECT '12-1' ORDER BY x+0;
+------+
| x    |
+------+
| 2-1  |
| 12-1 |
+------+
```

Answer (score 0):

You have ignored the [first rule of relational database design](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form). The solution is to split the identifier across three attributes in the table. Anything else is a workaround.

Assuming that there is some valid reason for this being impossible, then a better workaround than those which have already been suggested would be to change the table as I describe, but rename it, and create a view with a concatenation of the three attributes using the original table name. But this will break naive code trying to write to the view attribute.